# Import error: module not found

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I am working on an [addon](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B35OsPAJ46kvaHBYUWpNUDJ0S1k&usp=sharing) and when I test installing it it works just fine, but when I reopen the Blender I get a message saying `"JARCH_materials" module not found`, even though it is in the same folder. Also why is it when I install it I don't get a remove button on the addon?

Comment: Did you install it via *User Preferences > Addons > Install from file...*?

Comment: yes @CoDEmanX, I did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this seems to be an issue with importing `bpy` into JARCH_matierals. I changed around the code so that `bpy` is passed into the function instead of being imported and I got it all to work together fine. This might be since `bpy` is already imported into the module? I don't know for certain.